# Odd Network Times

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, visual-studio-2015, localhost

I did some refactoring to a Web API service, and I've been trying to make sure I didn't impact performance. Here's what I'm seeing in Chrome's DevTools:

[image: Network tab in Chrome's DevTools]

There's two things that strike me as weird:

- The Request Sent/Sending time for the POST requests is unusually long

  - As far as I'm aware, I cannot control this
  - The visible times, grouped, are roughly 250ms, 2.5s, and 750ms
- The last two OPTIONS requests are long

The TTFB times (the green bars) are about right for the POST requests, but the overall performance of the test page is poor, and I'm not sure there's anything I can actually do to fix it. **How should I address this behavior?**

The image captures a page using the service. Both website and service are running locally in Debug mode on IIS Express. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.

Comment: Are results coming from a database in the Server?  Are all request done at same time of day?  Are results repeatable?

Comment: The web service does interact with a database not hosted locally. Results are repeatable any time (though I haven't tried non-work hours).

Comment: With the long delay associated with specific database items (and repeatable) I would look at the database to understand why the query is taking longer than other queries.

Comment: The database connection isn't the issue. I'm satisfied with the TTFB times of the POST requests which would include the connection to the database. Please reread the question and let me know if it's still unclear what I'm asking.

Comment: I not talking about connection times.  The actual query times of retrieving the data.  Not all data comes comes out of database in same amount of time.  It is strange that 488 bytes of data is taking over 2 seconds to retrieve.  Another possibility is a firewall or virus checker looking at data contents and seeing data that may be unacceptable.

Comment: We're still not on the same page. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the Request Sent/Sending time is the time the browser takes to send the request and [shouldn't be taking this long](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112198/discussion-between-ricksmt-and-jdweng).